# Changing search behavior in jquery plugin Chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the Chosen plugin for jQuery and would like the search behavior to change a bit (single select). Searching only results in hits where the beginning of a word in the seach string matches. I would like to extend this to also hit words after slash and brackets.

For example:
search string: "**second**" does not match items "**first/second**" or "**first (second)**".

I doubt this is changeble by simply adding options to constructor, but I am willing to change/hardcode source script.

Chosen: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen

Answer (score 82, accepted):

As mentionned in some more recent answers, the plugin now implemements an option to change the search behavior:

```
search_contains: true
```

[Options documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html)

---

The plugin does not provide an option to change the search method behavior.

If you're willing to change the plugin source itself, here's a way to do it.

The method that makes the search in the plugin is `Chosen.prototype.winnow_results`. It uses a regular expression that matches text that "starts with" the search term:

```
// "^": means "starts with"
// "searchText" is the text in the search input (it is just cleaned up don't be scared)
regex = new RegExp('^' + searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'i');
```

Change it to:

```
regex = new RegExp(searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'i');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/vXFpW/)**

Comment: Very good! This also results in hits for searchTerm="cond", wich I actually wasnt looking for, but it is in this case totally acceptable.

Comment: Look at the answer by @DirkNguyen below.  It is the most up-to-date, now, and requires no modifications to the plugin.

Answer (score 45):

The search behavior can be set with the option `search_contains`

This is by default `false`

Set it to `true`, and chosen will also find matches inside instead of only the beginning:

```
$('#my_dropdown').chosen({ search_contains: true });
```

Comment: It seems that today's chosen version searches at the beginning of a `word`: so if I type **t** within the input and the `select` bound to the chosen object has an option like 'Some **t**ext', it will be listed in the dropdown...Is there a way to inhibit this behaviour and truly search only from the start of the option's text?

Comment: Is this disabled by default for performance reasons? If so how large is the performance change.

Answer (score 7):

As in Chosen 1.0, just add option {search_contains: true}

```
$('.selector').chosen({search_contains: true});
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

in chosen 1.0 i did on line 301&302

```
escapedSearchText = searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
regexAnchor = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is option `search_contains` available to search sub-string in options and can be used as:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
    search_contains: true
});
```