# Issue with chosen harvesthq's jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-chosen

I'm using this plugin

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

and I have an specific problem when I search some options with blanks.
for example I have an option tha is "Antigua y barbuda"
if I type :

1. Antigua y barbuda -> ok
2. Antigua y         -> ok
3. barbuda           -> ok
4. y                 -> ok
5. y barbuda         -> fail

it only fails when I start writing not the first word (only in cases that has blanks)

Regex:

```
regex = new RegExp(regexAnchor + searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'i');
zregex = new RegExp(searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'i');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing search behavior in jquery plugin Chosen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274362/changing-search-behavior-in-jquery-plugin-chosen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it removing "\s"

```
zregex = new RegExp(searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#]/g, "\\$&"), 'i');
```

Comment: all piola with you @Nicosunshine

Answer (score 4):

This is might be a Chosen problem.
Try using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) plugin, which originate from Chosen and its much better. Plus it allows custom matcher function so you can resolve your problem manually.

Comment: I was having similar problems with Chosen not matching multiple words. I switched to Select2 and all is now working...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to remove \s just set search_contains: true

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen({search_contains: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

For Joomla developers with similar issues:

```
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select', null, array('search_contains' => true));
```