# Chosen jQuery plugin search with spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have a problem with the Chosen jQuery [plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). When I try to search for a string which has space in it I get no results even if it does exist.

For example:
If I enter the string "and barbu" I don't get anything back. But when I write "antigua and barbu" I get the result.

What should I do to fix this space problem?

Comment: Either try some of the [options](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) (setting search_contains to true may work) or submit a bug report [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html)

Comment: Same problem here, if you don't search from the start of the string (ie "Antigua and"... instead on "gua and") got no result. Problem is for me, it's a tree select with many > beside every option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing search behavior in jquery plugin Chosen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274362/changing-search-behavior-in-jquery-plugin-chosen)

Answer (score 27):

Answer here : [Changing search behavior in jquery plugin Chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9274362/2846837)
Just need to add

```
jQuery('select').chosen({search_contains:true}) ;
```

As mentionned on the options doc :
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html

search_contains false   By default, Chosen’s search matches starting at the beginning of a word. Setting this option to true allows matches starting from anywhere within a word. This is especially useful for options that include a lot of special characters or phrases in ()s and []s.