# Chosen: search from begin of string

Tags: jquery-chosen

I'm using jQuery Chosen plugin to improve my select box, this is an example of the data:

```
Foobar Oooa
Ooafas Oob
Boombox Oooc
```

If I write in the search field of the selectbox `oo` it matches all the 3 elements, instead I'd like to match just the one which starts with `oo`.

I've tried with `enable_split_word_search` but seems to do nothing... Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i finally figured it out after a while of try and error :D

you have more than one word in the options, and the plugin searches for the input at the start of every word, so even if you set search_contains to false, the second word in each option (Oooa, Oob and Oooc) matches. To disable this behaviour, you have to add "enable_split_word_search": false (as you already mentioned)

```
$(".test").chosen({
    search_contains: false,
    enable_split_word_search: false
});
```

if that doesn't work you probably don't have the latest version of chosen

here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/UjCr7/4/

i tried different versions of the plugin and it didn't work with all of them, so if you want to use the version i have, just download v1.1.0 from https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the property

```
search_contains: false
```

if you set it to true it means, that it doesn't matter where the searched string is in the result, but if it is false, the searched text has to be in the beginning

Comment: Seems to not have any effect :(

Comment: then maybe you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274362/changing-search-behavior-in-jquery-plugin-chosen, but you have to add the ^ in the beginning instead of removing it

Comment: are you sure that you don't have accidentaly set this to true a bit later in your code? because if you look at the documentation: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html, it say's that this option is exactly what you want

Comment: I call chosen only one time so I don't think I can overwrite something, may you provide a working fiddle plase?