# Insert Input text in a Select as option

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, select

I'm doing a list, and the user can filter it with a *input* text. Now, the field is separated from the *select*, and I would set the *input* as an option, like in this image [image]

This is my [CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/h1OIfoUlwebvvfMRPWgj?p=preview). Thank you very much!

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    Search: <input ng-model="query"> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <!--Body content-->

    <select class="phones">
      <option ng-repeat="phone in phones.data | filter:query">
        <span>{{phone.name}}</span>  
        <span>{{phone.age}}</span>
      </option>
    </select>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that if no matching result is found in the Select box that a new 'option' entry is added as the value of your query?

Comment: No, i'm saying to transform the first <option> in the search box. Like this one: http://codepen.io/PageOnline/pen/nCfAj but instead of the <ul> and <li> i need a <select>, which the first <option> is the input for the search

Comment: You want something similar to https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select? With demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview ?

Comment: Yes, before i've found that and tried to integrate with my code but the code of ui-select is too much hard for me

Comment: It seems perfect! Unfortunately, the filter is only for the initial letters..... I need to look up a word by typing , if desired, only the last letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a somewhat complex task, I recommend you use an existing component/library unless your requirements are very, very special.

I can recommend **Chosen**, which will help you create dropdown menus with filtering through textbox:

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen

Regarding your requirement from the comments, the need to search not only from the beginning of a word, there is an option in Chosen to achieve that - it's called "search_contains". Refer to Chosen documentation for details:

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html

Also see this StackOverflow question regarding "search_contains":

[Changing search behavior in jquery plugin Chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274362/changing-search-behavior-in-jquery-plugin-chosen)

Comment: I deleted my original comment regarding Chosen, because I accidentally linked it to a fork other than the original.