# Jquery Chosen dropdown search based on Id of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

I have used Chosen dropdown successfully [code here](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

I want to search the text in dropdown based on there Id also.

like in below example

```
         <select chosen data-placeholder="Select Country" class="chosen-select" id="txtcontry" 
         ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for countryName in CountryNames" ng-model="country.Id">
            <option value="Select Country"></option>
        </select>
```

And I get my like like below
[image]

Now every `country Name` has a `Id` associated with it.
So I want to `search` by `name` as well as `Id` also.

For example If country name is `United States` and its `Id` is `100`
then If I put `100` then it should show me `United States` as output.

Comment: could you create a plunker,https://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9274362/2333214

Comment: choosen hides the original select drop down. I don't think your filter work with choosen. you have to write this functionality on your own.

Comment: use this http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/vXFpW/ or http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/282/